# convertNumber shows 0,00 as a negative value

Tags: jsf

When I try to show a number less than 0 like this:

```
<p:column headerText="value">
    <h:outputText value="-0,000001">
        <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"
            type="number" />
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

it shows -0,00

I need to show the number as 0.00 not as -0.00

How can I fix this bug?

Does anyone know?

Comment: But your value is negative

Comment: Yes, but 0 is not negative

Comment: The functionality you see is 100% correct.

Comment: your number is not 0.  This statement is true throughout the known universe: "-0.000001 != 0".  Your number is -0.000001, therefore all numbers are socrates.

Comment: Consider using BigDecimal even though that pains. Then a precision can be maintained in the number itself.

Comment: `-0.00` is mathematically invalid. You need at least one digit non-zero to do it.

Comment: Exactly, JSF shows -0.00 instead of 0.00. What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a bug. You have to distinguish its display-value from its value. Here `<f:convertNumber>` is merely a string formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed specified behavior. This is not exactly JSF's fault. The [`<f:convertNumber>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertNumber.html) uses [`java.text.NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) under the covers for the job which is just part of standard Java SE. There's no way to overcome this by some magic `NumberFormat` pattern or property. You'd really need to resort to string matching and manipulation.

Given the functional requirement as follows:

> *When the number contains only zeroes, then get rid of the minus sign.*

The solution is to create a custom converter which extends JSF's [`NumberConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/NumberConverter.html) and overrides its `getAsString()` with the necessary string matching and manipulation job:

```
@FacesConverter("customNumberConverter")
public class CustomNumberConverter extends NumberConverter {

    public CustomNumberConverter() {
        setMinFractionDigits(2);
        setMaxFractionDigits(2);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        String converted = super.getAsString(context, component, value);

        if (converted.charAt(0) == '-' && converted.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").matches("0+")) {
            return converted.substring(1);
        }
        else {
            return converted;
        }
    }

}
```

Which is to be used as follows (note that you cannot specify multiple converters on a single component, that's also why I took over the properties you initially set on `<f:convertNumber>`):

```html
<h:outputText value="#{-0.000001}" converter="customNumberConverter" />
```

*(note that I placed the hardcoded number value in valid `double` syntax (with period as fraction separator) in an EL expression; it's otherwise treated as a `String` instead of as `Number`; it'll just work for bean properties)*.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check the range of the number and display accordingly, by doing it in the value attribute of the h:outputText itself ? I see a trivial mathematical solution using basic logical operations rather than this boilerplate coding.

Comment: @Sujan: that's definitely easier, but not reusable/maintainable like a converter. You end up copypasting the same EL boilerplate coding over all place. Another way would be to parse it as `Number` again inside the converter and then do the math on it. That would end up in more clean code, but I think it's more awkward: parsing a number twice?

Comment: You have a good point about maintainability, especially when you have to do this at many places. But then, you could implement a method(s) that does the same job and could use it in the Facelet. Anyway, any design decision highly depends on the requirements. I think OP needs to be careful here, any rounding and formatting of numbers must be done in the backing bean and on the value itself, and not on the rendered view's representation (display-value). Otherwise, he might encounter 'unexpected' values later, during the processing (if any), and might be wondering what's happening..

Comment: @BalusC it doesn't work for me. I put a breakpoint in the getAsString method and it doesn't stop there. I think that getAsString method is not being called

Comment: Did you remove the `<f:convertNumber>`? If you keep it in, it would override any converters set in `converter`. You can have only one converter. That's exactly why I extended `NumberConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider math.

When a number is less than zero it is negative.

If you display two digits to the right of the decimal and your number is negative, but has a value that is less than 1/100 then the value will still be negative, but will display as 0.00.

Here is a detailed walkthrough of what is happening:

1. You tell JSF, "I want you to output the string value `-0.000001`".
2. You tell JSF, "That thing I told you to output, convert it to a number, then output it with only 2 digits to the right of the decimal point.
3. JSF converts "-0.000001" to a number.  The value is negative 0.000001 (or -0.000001).
4. JSF displays the value with only two digits to the right of the decimal place, which shows as "-0.00".

### Edit

To perform rounding on your value, you will need to either implement a custom converter or perform rounding on the value in the getter.

Here is a [Custom Converter Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_customconvertor_tag.htm)

Or if the actual page looks something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{blam.blamValue}">
```

You can add a new getter to your `blam` bean to round.
Perhaps resulting in something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{blam.roundedBlamValue}">
```

in the `getRoundedBlamValue` method you will need to address the -0 issue in java code.

Comment: Ok, what can I do to round my number?

Comment: @JohnB return a scaled and rounded `BigDecimal`. You have many solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug: The number is truncated, so you are showing part of it, but it still is a negative number.
I think the problem is you thought that convertNumber rounds it, but it just formats it. If you want a absolute 0, then round it before.